# remove duplicate VB.NET TreeVeiw node

Tags: vb.net

any hint on how to add only one node to TreeVeiw control while many nodes with same name found in access database field ?
I can loop through the field but all the values add to TreeNode which is why i wanted to remove the duplicate.

Comment: Fancy sharing your existing code and what you've already tried?

Comment: Just fix it in your dbase query, use DISTINCT.  And if that's not suitable for some reason (?) then just don't add a duplicate, no point in trying to remove them again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind response Mr Hans. i have tried but may be because am selecting the all fields it not working. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the items and store them in an array while doing so.
If the current item in the loop, already exists in the array => duplicate => remove

You could try that, good luck.

Comment: Thanks Dries your hint really help me. It works fine.